# Rails 4 - devise works in development mode but not in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, dev-to-production

My devise/omniauth works in my development mode (after 3.5 years of trying to set it up).

When I push to production and try to login, I get an error that says the following:

```
app/models/user.rb:159:in `find_for_oauth'
2016-06-26T00:24:21.173282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-26T00:24:21.173264+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-26T00:24:21.173279+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPFatalError (553-5.1.2 The recipient address <change@me-114727432687651490566-google_oauth2.c
```

Line 159 of my user model has:

```
    user.save!
```

That line is one of the last steps in a method with:

```
 def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
    # Get the identity and user if they exist
    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

    # If a signed_in_resource is provided it always overrides the existing user
    # to prevent the identity being locked with accidentally created accounts.
    # Note that this may leave zombie accounts (with no associated identity) which
    # can be cleaned up at a later date.
    user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

    # p '11111'

    # Create the user if needed
    if user.nil?
      # p 22222
      # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us a verified email.
      # If no verified email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the
      # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
      email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
      email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified # take out this if stmt for chin yi's solution
      user = User.where(:email => email).first if email

      # Create the user if it's a new registration
      if user.nil?
        # p 33333
        user = User.new(
          # at least one problem with this is that each provider uses different terms to desribe first name/last name/email. See notes on linkedin above
          first_name: auth.info.first_name,
          last_name: auth.info.last_name,
          email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
          #username: auth.info.nickname || auth.uid,
          password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
# fallback for name fields - add nickname to user table
        # debugger

        if email_is_verified
           user.skip_confirmation!
        end
        # user.skip_confirmation! 

        user.save!
      end
    end

    # Associate the identity with the user if needed
    if identity.user != user
      identity.user = user
      identity.save!
    end
    user
  end
```

Can anyone see what I need to do to make this work in production mode?

Comment: I think you're trying to send an email to an Oauth proxy email address, one that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @tadman I don't know what an auth proxy email address is. The error has this in it: Net::SMTPFatalError (553-5.1.2 The recipient address <change@me-113115134747932149496-google_oauth2.c
Thats the address when you sign up with an unconfirmed email address. The code isn't supposed to shut down with an error in that case, its supposed to let you register and edit your email address on a confirmation token

Comment: A proxy address is one that's given when an email address is required but the one the person has is not disclosed for security reasons. You get a stub, an email address that has all the properties of an email address except you can't deliver to it. Devise is trying to confirm this user, but with Oauth that's not necessary. If you can Oauth them, you should have enough information to validate their account.

Comment: @tadman can you think what I can do to get this working? I can oauth- im using google omniauth to sign up. This all works fine in development but its gone awry in production.